# Freeing a tree structure in C

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm using a tree of structs in my C program, where the struct is set up like so:

```
typedef struct SymbolTable_t
{
    int id;

    Symbol symbols[size];
    int count;
    struct SymbolTable_t * parent;

    int scopeCount;
    struct SymbolTable_t * childScopes[size];

    int isM;
} SymbolTable;
```

And when I create a new SymbolTable I allocate memory for the child scopes like this:

```
SymbolTable *t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
// other stuff ...
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   childScopes[i] = malloc(sizeof(SymbolTable)); // <---- line 41
}
```

And at the end of my program when I want to free the memory allocated to them I wrote a recursive function:

```
void freeSymbolTables(SymbolTable* root)
{
    if(root == NULL) return;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        freeSymbolTables(root->childScopes[i]);
    }
    free(root);
}
```

Note that I don't really use entirety of childScopes, so only some of them will actually point to something by the end of the program. I thought this was fine but running in valgrind it tells me a significant amount of memory is 'definitely lost' at line 41, which I think means the pointers are going out of scope without a call to free at the end of the program lifetime. I'm unsure what's going wrong here since I think this should free all the memory.

**Minimal reproducible example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define s_size 40

typedef struct SymbolTable_t
{
    struct SymbolTable_t * s[s_size];
    int count;
} SymbolTable;

SymbolTable* createSymbolTable()
{
    SymbolTable* t = malloc(sizeof *t);
    t->count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s_size; i++)
    {
        t->s[i] = malloc(sizeof t->s[i]);
    }
    return t;
}

void freeSymbolTable(SymbolTable* root)
{
    if(root == NULL) return;
    for(int i = 0; i < root->count; i++) freeSymbolTable(root->s[i]);
    for(int i = root->count; i < s_size; i++) free(root->s[i]);
    free(root);
}

void addChildScope(SymbolTable* parent, SymbolTable* child)
{
    parent->s[parent->count++] = child;
}

int main()
{
    SymbolTable *t =  createSymbolTable();
    SymbolTable *c = createSymbolTable();
    addChildScope(t, c);
    freeSymbolTable(t);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, valgrind tells me 8 bytes are definitely lost, even thought I think that my function should free all the memory.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. i've added a one file example, should be much easier to check

Comment: side note: `#define s_size 40` prefer to use upper case for macro constants, like `#define S_SIZE 40`. `for(int i = 0; i < root->count; i++) freeSymbolTable(root->s[i]);` why are you freeing it recursively? The childs are not initalized, the values in them are indeterminate. Did you mean to do `t->s[i] = malloc(..)` and then initialize it with `t->s[i]->count = 0;`? Also `freeSymbolTable(root->s[i]);` will do `free(root)` on itself , so don't `free(root->s[i]);` then again - it's double free.

Comment: @KamilCuk well for the example with one child symbol table, when it's created it calls malloc 40 times for it's children, so wouldn't I have to free all of those as well as itself? and when it returns up to the calling function where root = t, it will effectively skip over that first child then free the rest of the memory it was allocated in createSymbolTable(). I was under the impression that you need a free for every call of malloc.

Comment: But why does it malloc 40 times? What for? It's just unused memory. Wouldn't you want to malloc when you `addChildScope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically doing:

```
// in createSymbolTable()
   t->s[0] = malloc(...);
```

and then:

```
// in addChildScope()
     parent->s[0] = child;      // malloc(...) from above is just lost...
```

You could "patch"/workaround it with:

```
void addChildScope(SymbolTable* parent, SymbolTable* child) {
    free(parent->s[parent->count]);
    parent->s[parent->count++] = child;
}
```

But overall I see no point in mallocing anything in `createSymbolTable` if the memory is never used anyway. Just don't malloc it in `createSymbolTable` anyway, the memory is not used.

Also, theoretically (but it's never used, so it does not matter) the line:

```
t->s[i] = malloc(sizeof t->s[i]);
```

is suspicious - it's meant to be:

```
t->s[i] = malloc(sizeof *t->s[i]);
```

Comment: Ok, I think this makes sense. So instead of mallocing 40 times, everytime I add a child scope I would just set t->s[t->count] = child? (where child has already been allocated memory in createSymbolTable)

Comment: `verytime I add a child scope I would just set t->s[t->count] = child?` yes, you never use the mallocated memory.